# Why does this Jasmine test fail and do all function have to be on the scope to be tested?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, jasmine

This is a two pronged question:

**First Question**

In Jasmine based Angular testing do all functions have to be on the scope to be tested? For example if I call a function in the test suite like this:

```
searchTabController.disableDateFields()
```

I get the following:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
```

**Second question** 
I'm trying to test that the property of a component was set. The first `expect` passes and determines whether or not the component exists but the second `expect` fails - why?

If I comment out the first 3 lines and run the second three it still fails - how should this be properly tested?

```
 it( 'disableDateFields() should disable all date fields', function() {

    // Passes
    expect( $('#visSearchFrom') ).toBeDefined();
    var strgState = $('#visSearchFrom').attr('disabled');
    expect( strgState ).toBe( 'disabled' );

    $('#visSearchFrom').prop('disabled', true);
    var state = $('#visSearchFrom').prop('disabled'); 
    expect( state ).toBe( true );  
});
```

The error returned from both fails is this:

```
* Expected undefined to be 'disabled'
```

or

```
* Expected undefined to be true
```

The actual function that I'm testing looks like this:

```
 function disableDateFields() {

        $('#visSearchFrom').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#visSearchTo').prop('disabled', true);
        $("input[name='chkCurrentWeek']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    };
```

Comment: Controllers should contain no DOM manipulation at all, otherwise it will be hard when come to unit testing like you are encountering.

Comment: The first line in the test, "expect( $('#visSearchFrom') ).toBeDefined();" will always be true since jquery will return an empty array in case it doesn't find anything, and not 'undefined'. In your test page, the #visSearchFrom is probably NOT in the html.

Comment: @runTarm i agree this is suppose to be done mainly through services but this project is near completion and we may not have time to refactor. The dev that made the function didn't know how angular worked and settled on the above

Comment: @YairTavor it is in the test html as a parameter for a div-id

Comment: If that the case, you should include more details such as a html template that contains those DOM elements you are querying. It will be easier for other people to try and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, then no. You can use 'this' inside the controller and then access it by injection the controller test.

```
angular.module('app').controller('searchTabController', function($scope){

    // Create the function as part of the controller object
    this.disableDateFields = function(){ ... };

    // expose it in the scope if you want to.
    $scope.disableDateFields  = this.disableDateFields;    

});
```

Then in the test:

```
var searchTabController;

inject(function($rootScope, $controller){
   searchTabController= $controller('searchTabController', {
       $scope : $rootScope
   });
}

searchTabController.disableDateFields();
```

Comment: Are these the only two options? Would the use of this be preferable if you don't need it to call on the scope? This is important as it will require the class to be refactored to contain one or the other

Comment: If you want, you could extract the function to a service, inject it to the controller and then test the service instead. If you want the function to be in the controller in a testable way you must use the 'this' notation or expose the function on the scope.